# VueJS - unable to read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, youtube, axios

I'm attempting to load Youtube Videos via their API, and in order to get the duration, I have to send a second API request. The issue I'm having is that sometimes this code works, sometimes it throws

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDetails' of undefined"
```

I think it is because when Vue is trying to access the property, it is not there. If I access the variable (resolvedVideoData) with the Vue Developer tool on a failed load, it has only resolved ONE video.

What am I doing wrong? I'm calling the API query in created(), so the DOM hasn't loaded yet?

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
    name: 'BlogGrid',
    data(){
        return {
          videos:[],
          base_url_youtube: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',
          videoId: [],
          resolvedVideoData: [],    
        }
    },
    watch: {
        videos: function (){
           var arrayLength = this.videos.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
              this.videoId.push(this.videos[i].id.videoId); 
            }
            this.getVideoDuration()
      }
  },
    created() {
      axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={{YOUTUBE_API_KEY}}&channelId={{ChannelID}}A&order=date&part=snippet%20&type=video,id&maxResults=50`)
        .then(response => {
          this.videos = response.data.items
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })
},
  methods: {
       getVideoDuration(){
        axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' + this.videoId.join(', ') + '&part=contentDetails&key={{YOUTUBE_API_KEY}}')
        .then(response => {
          this.resolvedVideoData = response.data.items
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })
 }
 }
}
</script>
```

Upon further checking, if I spam the generated URL for the Google API, it seems like sometimes it's returning one value, sometimes it's returning all the values.

Since it was asked for

```
 <section class="blog-area ptb-80">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div
            v-for="(item, index) in videos"
            :key="item.etag"
            class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"
          >
            <div class="single-blog-post">
              <div
                class="blog-image"
                :href="base_url_youtube + item.id.videoId "
              >
                <a :href="base_url_youtube + item.id.videoId ">
                  <img
                    :src="item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url"
                    name="videoicon"
                    alt="image"
                  ></a>
                <a :href="base_url_youtube + item.id.videoId ">
                  <div class="overlay hidden-sm">
                    <div class="text">
                      {{ parseDuration(resolvedVideoData[index].contentDetails.duration) }}
                      <br>
                      <a :href="base_url_youtube + item.id.videoId"> <feather type="monitor" /></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </a>
                <div class="date">
                  <feather type="calendar" />
                  {{ format_date(item.snippet.publishedAt ) }}
                </div>
                <div class="blog-post-content">
                  {{ item.snippet.title }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

with my other methods being.

```
format_date(value){
          if (value) {
            return moment(String(value)).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
           }
       },
parseDuration(e){
    var n = e.replace(/D|H|M/g,":").replace(/P|T|S/g,"").split(":");

    if(1 == n.length)
        2!=n[0].length && (n[0]="0"+n[0]),n[0]="0:"+n[0];
    else 
        for(var r=1, l=n.length-1; l>=r;r++)
            2!=n[r].length && (n[r]="0"+n[r]);

    return n.join(":")
},
```

Comment: Hard to say, since none of the code posted tries to access a property called `contentDetails` -perhaps the error is in your template

Comment: It's just some HTML which accesses it, I can post it but I didn't want to make the post really large. I have added it for you

Comment: you're iterating over `videos` and using the index to access `resolvedVideoData` ... are you sure the two arrays are the same length? and `video[n]` is at all related to `resolvedVideoData[n]` ?

Comment: They should be the same length, sometimes they are, sometimes they are not. If you spam the API request you get variable different responses to the same request

Comment: `sometimes they are, sometimes they are not` - you need to handle the cases where videos length is greater than resolvedVideoData length ... perhaps by passing `resolvedVideoData[index]` to `parseDuration` and put the logic in there to check if the passed in object is undefined, or indeed has `contentDetails` property - though, if the two arrays are unrelated, I can't see how the code would be at all useful

Comment: I understand, but why is the API returning inconsistent results, it shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: oh, why is the API returning inconsistent results? That would be a youtube screw up :p